# React Redux, useSelector causing component to render twice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a user area for a react app,

If the user is logged in then the data is stored in redux under 'userData',

The problem I've got is that if a suer does to the user area when they are not logged in, I want the app to redirect them to another 'notloggedin' page,

I've got the below, however the problem I've got is when the route is first rendered `userDetails`is returning an empty object which subsequently triggers the `history.push('/notloggedin')`. I can see if I remove the `history.push('/notloggedin')` and load the component first time round it loads `userDetails` as an empty object, but then rerenders as a populated object. I'm really stuck on how to only cause the component to render once the object has been populated from useSelector.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useSelector, shallowEqual} from 'react-redux';

const index = () => {
    const userDetails = useSelector(state=>state.userData, shallowEqual);

useEffect(()=>{
    if(Object.keys(userDetails).length===0){
        history.push('/notloggedin')
    }
},[])
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Member Area</h1>
            <p>Your User name us</p>
            {userDetails.username}
            ...
        </div>
    );
};

export default index;
```

if I remove the line `const userDetails = useSelector(state=>state.userData, shallowEqual);`then the component only renders once as I would expect, I can't see why the above live is causing it to render twice!

userData is populated with the below action

```
//login/actions.js

export const getUserData = (token) => {
    console.log('getuser data');
    return dispatch => {
        api.getUserData()
        .then(res =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_USER_DETAILS,
                payload: res.data.user
            })
        );
    };
};
```

which is called in `App.js`

```
//App.js


const App = () => {
    

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
       
        if (localStorage.getItem("userToken")) {
            
    
    dispatch(getUserData(localStorage.getItem("userToken")));
        }
        
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="app">
           ...
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is `userData` populated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you are setting your user state once components are rendered (you are setting the user state using `useEffect` in `App.js`).

First render with the user state being null -> useEffect dispatchs the user data retrieved from local storage -> user state gets updated -> another render since you are listening to the state change.

If you want to set your user data using local storage, I recommend doing that when initialing your redux state.